# Resource Group name case insensitive in Disk IDs

Tags: azure, resources, disk

The case of resource group names in IDs of disks are case insensitive.
Steps to reproduce this issue -

1. Create a standalone disk in Azure, check for ID. For eg -
   "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/**diskRG1**/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/TestVM_disk2" . Notice the case of resource group name -> "**diskRG1**".
2. Create a VM.
3. Attach the disk created disk (in step 1) to VM.
4. Go to newly created VM->Disks-> Check for the attached Disk ID and it displays as -> "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/**DISKRG1**/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/TestVM_disk2" . Now the resource group name has changed to **DISKRG1**.

IDs of disk should be same and case sensitive. 
Is this a known issue ?

Comment: Any updates on the above issue ?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer to a similar problem here
[Azure ARM API returns locations with inconsistent case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50068324/azure-arm-api-returns-locations-with-inconsistent-case/50977265#50977265)

Azure ARM is case insensitive so this is expected, and your code should adapt to it.