# Azure ARM API returns locations with inconsistent case

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

azure vm list and azure location list command shows different capitalization for location for some regions such as CanadaEast (might also happen in other locations)

Steps to reproduce:

Deploy a vm in Canada East
Run azure vm list
run azure location lists ...
When you compare outputs you get different capitalization for CanadaEast but other older regions such as North Europe are always in lowercase

```
$ azure location list data: data: Location : **canadaeast** data: DisplayName : Canada East data: Providers : Microsoft.ApiManagement, Microsoft.Batch, Microsoft.ClassicCompute, Microsoft.ClassicNetwork...
`

10:55 $ azure vm list
info:    Executing command vm list
+ Getting virtual machines                                                     
data:    ResourceGroupName  Name             ProvisioningState  PowerState  Location     Size       
data:    -----------------  ---------------  -----------------  ----------  -----------  -----------
data:    RG2FAILIMPORT      importmustfail   Succeeded          VM running  northeurope  Standard_A1
data:    ABIQUO-CANADAEAST  abq-8e2f880d-7f  Succeeded          VM running  **CanadaEast**   Basic_A0   
data:    ABIQUO-CANADAEAST  abq-db821ef0-b5  Succeeded          VM running  **CanadaEast**   Basic_A0   
info:    vm list command OK
```

`

This behavior is inconsistent and causes issues with 3rd party tools when comparing or accessing resources in these regions. It's not limited to VirtualMachines and also happens with Images and other resources

Comment: I'm afraid this is not an Azure bug report forum, nothing we can help you with here, just use something like `.tolower()` to compare things.

Comment: Well, according to @AzureSupport twitter THIS is the place to report these kind of things...yeah, it probably shouldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gleb is spot on - ARM is not case sensitive, so your code should not be either.

Comment: I agree with this and will change code. What i'd like to do is report his inconsistency in Azure API somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft finally fixed this inconsistency and all locations are returned in lowercase now so the issue no longer exists.

However it's still true all code using this API should be case insensitive to avoid problems.